# send text file (column data with space) in a table format in mail body

Tags: shell-script, shell

Can anyone help me to send below data in html table format in mail body using shell script.
sample file

```
abcd "this is to test" 123
csdf "another test" 10000
```

I have created below script but it breaks when there is space in the second column value

```
echo "send an email"
awk 'BEGIN {
 print "<html><body><table border=1 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=3>"
 print "<tr>"
 print "<td>date</td>";
 print "<td>name</td>";
 print "<td>total</td>";
 print "</tr>"
} {
 print "<tr>"
 print "<td>"$1"</td>";
 print "<td>"$2"</td>";
 print "<td>"$3"</td>";
 print "</tr>"
} END {
 print "</table></body></html>"
} ' sample.txt >> sample.html
(
echo "To: xyz@gt.com"
echo "MIME-Version: 1.0"
echo "Subject:$v_subject"
echo "Content-Type: text/html"
cat sample.html
) | sendmail -t
```

Comment: awk doesn't care that quotes are meant to remove the special meaning of white space. The GNU AWK manual [covers this problem](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Splitting-By-Content), though it uses commas as delimiters in the example, to allow processing CSV files.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `awk`, consider using the appropriate tools:

- Read `csv` with a proper CSV parser
- Separate the `html` template from your code with a template engine.

---

I'd go with `python` which provides both, but that is a matter of choice.

Here a working example:

--> `script.py`

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

import csv
from jinja2 import Template
import sys

templ = '''<html>
<body>
<table border=1 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=3>
  <tr>
    <td>date</td>
    <td>name</td>
    <td>total</td>
  </tr>
  {% for row in rows %}<tr>
    {% for col in row %}<td>{{col}}</td>{% endfor %}
  </tr>{% endfor %}
</table>
</body></html>
'''

with open(sys.argv[1]) as csvfile:
    rows = list(csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=' '))

tm = Template(templ)
print(tm.render(rows=rows))
```

- Run `python script.py sample.csv > sample.html`
- For the sake of convenience, I included the template as string in the code, you should consider using a separate template file
- You can surely send the email directly via `python` too :-)

---

You may need to [install `jinja2`](https://pypi.org/project/Jinja2/):

```
pip install jinja2
```

Comment: I would prefer to use shelll as entire processing is happening in shell, If I have to do it in python, have to make a lot of changes and have to run all together a new process, Need to find a solution in shell

Comment: But your script is calling `awk`. Regarding that `python` is available almost everywhere what is the difference? You can simply implement this in your shell procedure the same like you do with your `awk` command.